# Readable format of file sizes using the Find command

Tags: shell-script, scripting, find, disk-usage

To see human readable output, I can use the following command –
du command -h option : Display sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K, 234M, 2G).

```
$ du -hsx * | sort -rh | head -10
```

The sample output would look like

```
4.4G   Desktop
3.8G   Downloads
149M   en-GB
146M   Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-GB.tar.gz
95M   scala-2.11.4.deb
20M   gawk-4.1.1
4.5M   linux-dash
3.9M   yii-1.1.13.e9e4a0.tar.gz.1
3.9M   yii-1.1.13.e9e4a0.tar.gz
```

How can I use the **Find** command to get the readable file sizes?

Example:
To skip directories and only display files, use the following command

```
find . -type f -printf '%s %p\n'| sort -nr | head -4
```

Gives me:

```
185016320 ./Desktop/gdb-7.9.tar
153300495 ./Downloads/apache-storm-1.0.0.tar.gz
152847886 ./Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-GB.tar.gz
98756608 ./scala-2.11.4.deb
```

**I'm trying to get the file sizes to show up as 185M, 153M, etc.. (more readable)**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `numfmt`

```
find . -type f -printf '%s %p\n'| sort -nr | head -4 | numfmt --field=1 --to=iec
```

Output:

```
177M ./Desktop/gdb-7.9.tar
147M ./Downloads/apache-storm-1.0.0.tar.gz
146M ./Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-GB.tar.gz
95M ./scala-2.11.4.deb
```

Use `--to=si` if you want factor 1000 instead of 1024